# Symfony1.2 component issue

Tags: symfony1, components, partial

I am struggling to call a component in another module where a called component using its own actions::functionname

For example

module/user/actions/actions.class.php have function like getUserName()
I am calling userActions::getUserName() function in same module's component, its working fine i.e

file: module/user/actions/components.class.php

```
public function executeShowUsername () {
$this->userName =userActions::getUserName();
}
```

in template of component (module/user/templates/_showUsername.php)
echo $userName;  (working fine )

Now, problem is:
When including ('user','showUserName') component in other module like
file: module/generate/template/indexSuccess.php

```
<?php include_component('user', 'showUserName'); ?>
```

I am getting error:

> Fatal error: Class 'userActions' not found in /myproject/apps/frontend/modules/user/actions/components.class.php on line 86

How can I resolve it?
Can't we call component in other module if it is calling function like
userActions::getUserName()

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the user session, you may just access it directly in your layout templating ( see User Session section in http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer):

`<?php echo $sf_user->getAttribute('nickname') ?>`

Otherwise, to pass variables to the component (see the Component section in http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer):

[from Listing 7-13 - Passing Parameters to a Component and Its Template]

```
// Call to the component
// rather than calling userActions::getUserName() in the component.class
// put your code from userActions::getUserName() into the model (or other accessible place)
// then call the component
<?php include_component('user', 'showUserName', array('MyUserName' => 'myuser')) ?>

// In the component itself
echo $this->MyUserName;
/* results in */ => 'myuser'

// In the _show_user_name.php partial
echo $MyUserName;
/* results in */ => 'myuser'
```

Comment: I am not working with session, in above example i have simply actually funtion to getUserName(),but it will great help to me if i can use showUserName component in any other module. 

Also i am not clear why i need to shift code from global access class file does the way i am trying to support in symfony1.2 ?

Comment: I think the way you are calling get userName() in a component with reference to the actions.class does not work with the design of the framework. That is why I think if you put the getUserName() function within the model, you would be able to access it within your component and include it in other modules. Hope this helps.